# How can I check if the adobe flash plugins is correctly installed in Mint 17.1?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, adobe-flash, plugin

I know that Linux Mint has the adobe flash plugin pre-installed, but I tried to update that and I think I made a mess, since the videos on `youtube.com`, and more generally, on the internet, are jerkily.

I want to check if everything is ok, but I do not know how i can do it without running the risk to worse everything.

The CPU information are the following:

```
-Model: AMD E1-2100 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics (Frequency 800.000 MHz, L2 cache 1024 Kb);
```

and I already installed Catalyst manager for that.

Someone can suggest the correct procedure to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this address and check:
https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

Also, you YouTube you could go to https://www.youtube.com/html5 and enable the HTML5 player and youtube will work better.